# Pass Images url using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to send with props some icons between two components. I import the urls and I'm using it to do the prop object.
This is my main file.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import SapIcon from '../images/logo_sap.png';
import ExcelIcon from '../images/logo_excel.png';
import OutlookIcon from '../images/logo_outlook.png';
import BrowserIcon from '../images/logo_webbrowser.png';
import OneDriveIcon from '../images/logo_onedrive.png';
import XhisIcon from '../images/logo_xhis.png';

import LeftBlock from './LeftBlock';

const BotsGrid = () => {
    const [icons, setIcons] = useState([{ 
        SapIcon: { SapIcon }, 
        ExcelIcon: { ExcelIcon }, 
        OutlookIcon: { OutlookIcon },
        BrowserIcon: { BrowserIcon },
        OneDriveIcon: { OneDriveIcon },
        XhisIcon: { XhisIcon }
    }]);

    console.log(icons.SapIcon);

    return (  
        <div className='BotsGrid'>
            <div class="site-section bg-light">
                <div class="container">

                <LeftBlock icons={icons} />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default BotsGrid;
```

I try to import this prop on my LeftBlock.js file but this doesn't work

```
const LeftBlock = (props) => {
    const icons = props.icons;


    return (  
        <div className="LeftBlock">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <div class="d-flex tutorial-item mb-4">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h3><a href="#">Test</a></h3>
                            <img src={ icons.SapIcon } alt="Image" width="12%" height="12%" class='mr-4'/>
                            <img src={ icons.ExcelIcon } alt="Image" width="8%" height="8%" class='mr-4' />
                            <img src={ icons.OutlookIcon } alt="Image" width="8%" height="8%" class='mr-4' />
                            </p>
                            <p class="meta">
                            <span class="mr-2 mb-2">Business</span>
                            </p>
                            <p><a href="bot_carga_fc_prov.html" class="btn btn-primary custom-btn">Details</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I need some help because the page doesn't show the icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using an array just remove it

```
const BotsGrid = () => {
const [icons, setIcons] = useState({ 
    SapIcon: SapIcon ,
    ExcelIcon: ExcelIcon,
    OutlookIcon: OutlookIcon ,
    BrowserIcon: BrowserIcon,
    OneDriveIcon: OneDriveIcon,
    XhisIcon: XhisIcon
});
```

Comment: I tried and it seems that I can pass the objects now, but the images hasn't worked yet, it says <img src="[object Object]" alt="Image" width="8%" height="8%" class="mr-4"> when I inspect the element

Comment: It was my fault, I was using { } to call the image links that iIimported, now it works! thank you so much!